# Caught TypeError in DataLoader worker process 0

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

```
max_epochs = 22
for epoch in range(max_epochs):
    model.to(device)
    
    # Training
    train_loss = 0
    model.train()
    for local_batch, (centers, lefts, rights) in enumerate(training_generator):
        # Transfer to GPU
        centers, lefts, rights = toDevice(centers, device), toDevice(lefts, device), toDevice(rights, device)
        
        # Model computations
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        datas = [centers, lefts, rights]        
        for data in datas:
            imgs, angles = data
            print("training image: ", imgs.shape)
            outputs = model(imgs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, angles.unsqueeze(1))
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            train_loss += loss.data[0].item()
            
        if local_batch % 100 == 0:
            print('Loss: %.3f '
                % (train_loss/(local_batch+1)))
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-5f093ac2d4e3> in <cell line: 2>()
      6     train_loss = 0
      7     model.train()
----> 8     for local_batch, (centers, lefts, rights) in enumerate(training_generator):
      9         # Transfer to GPU
     10         centers, lefts, rights = toDevice(centers, device), toDevice(lefts, device), toDevice(rights, device)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/_utils.py in reraise(self)
    642             # instantiate since we don't know how to
    643             raise RuntimeError(msg) from None
--> 644         raise exception
    645 
    646 

TypeError: Caught TypeError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 308, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 51, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 51, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "<ipython-input-13-19d4a742dd38>", line 10, in __getitem__
    center_img, steering_angle_center = augment(batch_samples[0], steering_angle)
  File "<ipython-input-11-d1f2a7cf14ec>", line 5, in augment
    current_image = current_image[65:-25, :, :]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I have been working with this existing code[Deep Learning for Self-Driving Cars](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-for-self-driving-cars-7f198ef4cfa2). But when I run the above block of code I am getting error. The error is being highlighted on this line for local_batch, (centers, lefts, rights) in enumerate(training_generator):. How can I get rid of this error?